# How to check if an object is a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have an `if` statement that needs to know if the object type is a button.

So far I have:

```
NSLog(@" %@ ",[myObject class]);
```

which returns `UIButton`, so I know that that is working.

Next is the `if` statement:

```
if([myObject isMemberOfClass:_______])
```

This is where I run into problems because I am not allowed to supply `UIButton` as the parameter for `isMemberOfClass:`.  I tried using `UIButtonTypeCustom`, but it didn't satisfy the `if` statement.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other answers and comments are getting at this already, but it could stand to be made clearer.

When you use `isMemberOfClass:`, the argument must be a `Class` object. You can get one of these for any class using the `class` selector. Hence:

```
if ([myObject isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    NSLog(@"It's a UIButton");
else
    NSLog(@"It's not a UIButton");
```

Now, `isMemberOfClass:` will only return `YES` if the object is specifically an instance of `UIButton`. However, it's more common to be interested in whether an object *inherits* from a particular class -- especially here, since UIKit may use private subclasses of `UIButton` behind the scenes. For that, you want `isKindOfClass:` instead:

```
if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    NSLog(@"It's a UIButton or some subclass");
else
    NSLog(@"It's not a UIButton");
```

Answer (score 1):

For is-a UIButton check, this is the preferred method
because it will check if it's a NSProxy standing in as an UIButton. Although it's doubtful that anyone would do that.

```
[myObject isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]
```

or (will fail if myObject is NSProxy standing in for UIButton)

```
if([myObject class] == [UIButton class])
```

For is-a or subclass of UIbutton

```
[myObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]
```

Generally you would want to use `[myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(someSelector:)]` or `[myObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(someProtocol)]` when using specific functions because myObject might not be the class you want but could implement the functionality needed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one is

```
if([myObj class] == [UIButton class])
```

As per your code you are missing

```
if([myObject isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
```

Comment: @lorean Yeah that doesn't work for subclasses nor `isMemberOfClass` will work. For that you have to use `isKindOfClass`

Comment: @HelloWorld it's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([myObject isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

}
```

OR

```
if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

}
```